# How to add validations on <aui:input type="editor" />?

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-aui

I want to apply validation on my rich-text in Liferay. I am using `<aui:input type="editor" name="description" localized="true" />`.
Now, when I try to use `<aui:validator name="required" />`, it is showing a red star mark on my rich text box as shown in the below image but a user can still be able to submit the form without entering the description:
[Description Rich Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXqcJ.png)

How can I restrict user to move further? Also, I want to apply some other validations of minimum, maximum character length